# Update existing records by data in different table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have the following schema in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_results (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    raw jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone  
);

CREATE TABLE slide_results (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    survey_result_id integer NOT NULL,
    slide_id integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone  
);



INSERT INTO survey_results (id, raw, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (1, '[{"id": "1", "finished_at": 1517421628092}, {"id": "2", "finished_at": 1517421894736}]', now(), now());


INSERT INTO slide_results (id, survey_result_id, slide_id, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (1, 1, 1, now(), now());

INSERT INTO slide_results (id, survey_result_id, slide_id, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (2, 1, 2, now(), now());
```

The problem is inside `slide_results` table. `created_at` column in this table contains invalid data. I want to update all `slide_results` `created_at` to be the same as the value of `raw->finished_at`.

Any idea of doing that operation like this in PostgreSQL?

Here is link to sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c47fc

Comment: How those tables related?

Comment: slide_results table have survey_result_id foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```
update slide_results
    set created_at = timestamp 'epoch' + (raw#>>'{1,"finished_at"}')::bigint * interval '1 millisecond'
    from survey_results sr
    where slide_results.survey_result_id = sr.id;
```

Comment: This query works, but when some of slide results do not have `finished_at` key in json then it fails with the following error:

`ERROR: null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains (1, 1, 1, null, 2018-03-05 12:29:10.746283).`

Comment: Also this not works correctly. Those `finished_at` are different but after trying Your query all slide results created_at is the same:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4c996/1

Comment: @MateuszUrbański . . . Your SQL Fiddle only has one value that is connected to both records.  Hence, the result is always the same.

Comment: I have two slide results which belongs to the same survey_result. But when You look at raw['slides'] You will find that those finished_at are different. First record in slide results table should have created_at updated to: 1517421628092 and the second one to 1517421894736.